# IndexOutOfRangeException when rounding off data

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, rounding, indexoutofrangeexception

I have the following `stored procedure`

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[spVerifyCustomerUserLogin]    

@EmbossLine varchar(16),    

@password varchar(50)    

as    

    Select C.EmbossLine,C.EmbossName,round(CB.TotalLoading,2),round(CB.Totalredemption,2),round(CB.CardBalance,2) 
    from Card C inner join CardBalance CB on CB.PAN=C.EmbossLine

    where 

    EmbossLine = @EmbossLine 

    and [password] = @password 

    and Status='E0'
```

and I have the following `VB.Net` code to access it:

```
Dim UserData As New ArrayList
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader
            dr = GenericDB.ExecuteSPForDataReader("spVerifyCustomerUserLogin", spParameters)
            If dr.HasRows Then
                dr.Read()
                UserData.Add(dr.Item("EmbossLine"))
                UserData.Add(dr.Item("EmbossName"))
                UserData.Add(dr.Item("TotalLoading"))
                UserData.Add(dr.Item("Totalredemption"))
                UserData.Add(dr.Item("CardBalance"))
                dr.Close()
                Return UserData
            End If
            dr.Close()
            Return UserData
```

Problem is my code throws an exception `IndexOutOfRangeException` on

```
UserData.Add(dr.Item("TotalLoading"))
```

Note that when I access the stored procedure without the `round` function it works fine so it has something to do with my round function. 
Note that my Fields `TotalLoading`, `TotalRedemption` and `CardBalance` are of type money. Is it because of that?

Comment: Are you sure that its a `IndexOutOfRangeException` and not an `ArgumentException`? Also, there is no reason to use the old non-generic `ArrayList` anymore. Instead use a custom class and fill f.e. a `List(Of ClassName)`.

Comment: Yes IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: I'm asking because [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says that an `ArgumentException` is thrown if you provide a columnname that does not exist in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's because you used a function on your totalLoading column and didn't alias it.

Change your SELECT statement in your stored proc to this:

```
 Select 
  C.EmbossLine,
  C.EmbossName,
  round(CB.TotalLoading,2) as TotalLoading,
  round(CB.Totalredemption,2) as TotalRedemption,
  round(CB.CardBalance,2) as CardBalance
        from Card C inner join CardBalance CB on CB.PAN=C.EmbossLine
```

Answer (score 2):

When you perform an operation on a column (e.g. `round(CB.TotalLoading,2)`) it no longer has a name. You can give it a name by using `AS`, like

```
SELECT C.EmbossLine, C.EmbossName, ROUND(CB.TotalLoading, 2) AS 'RoundedTotalLoading',...
```